# Performance when adding new elements after existing ones to a LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

Let's assume we have a java.util.LinkedList containing a few hundreds of elements. One possibility to insert a new element E after the an existing element K would be:

```
list.add(list.indexOf(K) + 1, E);
```

As far as I understand this method has an O(k<sup>2</sup>) behavior where k denotes the position of element K. First indexOf() runs through the list until it finds K and afterwards add has to do the same work again until it reaches position k + 1. But the entries which have to be modified could in easily be determined after the first step. I think it wouldn't be that much work to create a method addAfter(K, E) with O(k) behavior.

Is there a way to improve the performance in a scenario like this one besides switching to java.util.ArrayList?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrong with your assumption, that it is O(k^2), its just O(2k) which is O(k) (Btw here must be not k=index of element, but size of list, but that doesnt matter for the problem). But you are right it takes twice as long and is inefficent. The only way I can think of is to use `ListIterator` and find/insert yourself (which is intended to do exactly this kind of manipulations).

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I understand this method has an O(k2) behavior where k denotes the position of element K. First indexOf() runs through the list until it finds K and afterwards add has to do the same work again until it reaches position k + 1.

Actually, the cost of `list.add(list.indexOf(K) + 1, E)` is `O(k)` if `list` is a `LinkedList`.

- The `list.indexOf(K)` call involves `k` link traversals and `k` comparisons.
- The `list.add(k + 1, E)` call involves `k + 1` link traversals.

Add them up - `3 k + 1` operations; i.e. `O(k)`.

---

However, you are right.  It would be possible to create an alternative version of `LinkedList` with an `addAfter` or `addBefore` method.  These methods would also be `O(k)` but they should be faster.  Unfortunately, `LinkedList` is not implemented in a way that would allow you to simply add these methods (and implement them optimally).  The internals of `LinkedList` are declared as private, so you would need to start over.

---

And incidentally `list.add(list.indexOf(K) + 1, E)` on an `ArrayList` will be `O(N)` where `N` is the list length.  The `indexOf` step takes `k` comparisons, and the `add` step involves moving `N - k` elements.  Ergo `N` operations and `O(N)`

Comment: Of course you're right. My bad. Still, could the number of link traversals be reduced?

Answer (score 1):

This sample of code is to make k operations:

```
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        list.add(i);
    }

    Integer insert = 1001;
    Integer before = 50;
    for (ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Integer next = iterator.next();
        if(next.equals(before)){
            iterator.add(insert);
            break;
        }
    }
```